# function call stops working after a logout and log back in via ssh

Tags: function, bash

I have 3 function calls being used in /root/.bash_profile on a RHEL 6 server.

```
func1 () {
  history_file=/root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}')
  HISTTIMEFORMAT='%Y/%m/%d %T ' history | sed '/^#/ d' >   "$history_file" ; }

func2 () {
  history_file=/root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}')
  /bin/cat "$history_file" >> /root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m |  awk '{print $1}').bak ; }

func3 () {
  histbakfile=/root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print   $1}').bak
  awk '!_[$0]++ {print}' "$histbakfile" | sort -nu > tmp.bak && mv -  f tmp.bak "$histbakfile" ; }


shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="func1;func2;func3;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Func1's responsibility is to create the history file for the logged in user.

Func2's responsibility is to combine the the contents of the history file into a history backup file as they are being written. This is done to prevent losing the history in the production history file if you were to clear the history. (running history -c)

Func3's responsibility is to run formatting on the backup file to remove duplicates and sort the order.

It looks like somehthing is wrong with func2, because that is where the breakdown is occurring. I can get it working again, if I clear the history and the contents of the backup file, but that only works until I logout and log back in. Once I do that, data is no longer appended to the backup file. Here is an example.

After I clear out history and run new commands

```
[root@rhel history]# echo "" > .bash_hist-user.bak 
[root@rhel history]# q
-bash: q: command not found
[root@rhel history]# w
root@rhel history]# e
-bash: e: command not found
[root@rhel history]# r
-bash: r: command not found
[root@rhel history]# t
-bash: t: command not found
[root@rhel history]#
```

Check history after I ran the commands above.

```
[root@rhel history]# history
1  2016/05/25 11:01:01 echo "" > .bash_hist-user.bak 
2  2016/05/25 11:01:05 q
3  2016/05/25 11:01:06 w
4  2016/05/25 11:01:06 e
5  2016/05/25 11:01:06 r
6  2016/05/25 11:01:07 t
7  2016/05/25 11:02:09 history
```

Its there. Now I check the history file.

```
[root@rhel history]# cat .bash_hist-user
1  2016/05/25 11:01:01 echo "" > .bash_hist-user.bak 
2  2016/05/25 11:01:05 q
3  2016/05/25 11:01:06 w
4  2016/05/25 11:01:06 e
5  2016/05/25 11:01:06 r
6  2016/05/25 11:01:07 t
7  2016/05/25 11:02:09 history
```

All there. Now I look at the backup file.

```
[root@rhel history]# cat .bash_hist-user.bak 

1  2016/05/25 11:01:01 echo "" > .bash_hist-user.bak 
2  2016/05/25 11:01:05 q
3  2016/05/25 11:01:06 w
4  2016/05/25 11:01:06 e
5  2016/05/25 11:01:06 r
6  2016/05/25 11:01:07 t
7  2016/05/25 11:02:09 history
8  2016/05/25 11:02:25 cat .bash_hist-user
```

All is there and all works fine. However whenever I log out and log back in regardless of what commands I run the backup file never gets appended any longer. I  cant even cat >> the history file into the backup file from command line. The command completes but does not append anything new. Neither does history -a,-r,-w, etc...

Is this a coding problem and if so what can I do to fix this?

NOTE - we always use sudo or plain su to get root after login, which is why these calls are in roots .bash_profile. But the "who -m" is what creates a separate file for each user of the system.

Comment: I'm not quite following.  You say you put the given function definitions into `/root/.bash_profile`, but ordinarily that would be used only to initialize `root`'s environment, not anyone else's.  As such, I'm not seeing how it makes sense to run `who` in those functions, for it seems that must always output "root".

Comment: no, who -m returns the "logged in" user, which is the user associated with stdin. So if I was to get sudo or root running who -m returns whose got the psuedo terminal, which is a regular user.

Comment: I made an edit to the post hopefully that clears up some confusion.

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic, but details matter.  `who -m` reports on the user associated with that command's own `stdin`.  If that file is ultimately provided by a user's login shell then in that sense yes, it will report on *that* logged in user.  But there may be more than one logged-in user, and the command's `stdin` does not necessarily come ultimately from a login shell.

Comment: In any case, it's still unclear what must be done to reproduce the error, because you leave a gap between a user logging in to an ordinary account and that user obtaining a root shell.  In particular, it is not clear whether a root shell is obtained in a manner that would result in `.bash_profile` being used.

Comment: There is really not much of a gap. As soon as we login, we get root via su. And, like I mentioned, steps to reproduce would be setting up this config. Sourcing .bash_profile. running some commands to watch it work. Then log out and back in, get root again and you can see that commands are no longer appended to the backup file. I thought I added in a ton of detail and info in my original post. If you can think of anything else let me know.

Comment: The *specific command* you use to get a root shell matters.  If you just `su` then you do not get a login shell.  If you `su -` then you do get a login shell.  `.bash_profile` is used only to configure login shells; `.bashrc` is used instead for non-login shells.

Comment: Additionally, I presume you already understand that the configuration you present will be active only in the shell configured as you described, maybe its subshells (depending on whether the functions and variable are exported), and maybe shells spawned by programs launched from such shells.